# The solution to my wind farm layout optimization using GA produces different results every time i run it. Is their a way to curb it?

Tags: genetic-algorithms

Each layout consists of 1000 turbines or more and is ranked based on power produced.
The way my algorithm works is:-

```
>>Initial parents created(2 layouts)
>>Crossover and Mutation of Initial Parents and population is created
>>Calculation of power produced by each layout
>>Sorting of layouts using power values
>>Top 2 layouts producing max power selected for next generation
>>The steps are repeated till termination criteria is reached
```

each time I run the algorithm, I get a different configuration of layout.
Can anyone help me out in reducing the ambiguity in the output?

Comment: Genetic algorithms produce a (hopefully not to bad) solution to a problem that satisfies certain constraints. It does so by *randomly* modifying a population of potential solutions and selecting the best. Unless by pure chance there is *one* best solution, and furthermore your algorithm hits it every single time, you'll get different output each time.